How to remove lines of file content, if has specific trailing string?
There is a file with this simple content:
projectA-app1
projectA-app2
projectA-app-mobile
projectB-app1

Now I need to get every application name into one line (removing line breaks)
apps=$(cat file.txt| tr -s '\n' ' ')

but I also need to remove all applications, which are ending with -mobile. How do I do that?
The result of this example should be
projectA-app1 projectA-app2 projectB-app1


Uh? echo $(grep -v "-mobile$" file.txt| tr \\n \ )

Or grep -v "-mobile$" file.txt|xargs Look for xargs about merging lines

You could reverse grep on mobile$ and then pass the result to tr:
grep -v -E 'mobile$' bla | tr -s '\n' ' '


You could also combine these 2 into a signle awk command:
awk '!/mobile$/ { printf "%s ", $0 } END { print "" }' bla


projectA-app1 projectA-app2 projectB-app1

